# PHP file upload issue with tmp_name

Tags: php

Issue with uploading **some** Images. I was trying to store image in mysql blob type. It was successful for some images but for some other images, it results in error.

warning in logs are as below:

```
Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\KITSW zone\Modules\Timeline\Admin\image_post.php on line 32

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\KITSW zone\Modules\Timeline\Admin\image_post.php on line 33

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\KITSW zone\Modules\Timeline\Admin\image_post.php on line 35
```

**php file code:**

```
            $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            $tmpname = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
            $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $fp      = fopen($tmpname, 'r');
            $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpname));
            $content = addslashes($content);
            fclose($fp);

            $final = "INSERT INTO `files`(`by_user`, `name`, `type`, `size`, `data`, `category`, `categoryid`) 
            VALUES('$by_user', '$filename','$file_type','$file_size','$content','timeline','$inserted')";
```

Comment: Are you using Ajax ? or just posting from HTML ?

Comment: @Nandan Bhat Using Jquery

Comment: Are you using <input type="file"> in your markups >

Comment: yeah @NandanBhat

Comment: Kindly show us your client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

> but for some other images, it results in error

This is the point....
Maybe you should add a var_dump($_FILES['userfile']) to check the property of those error images.